# Superfluous processes in multiprocessing

Tags: linux, python-2.7, multiprocessing

Python multiprocessing generates more processes than it should. The problem is only on Linux, but not on OSX or Windows . For example, 5 processes will be created for the following code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import numpy as np
import os

def f(x):
    time.sleep(x)
    print(os.getpid())

pool = mp.Pool(1)
pool.map(f, np.random.rand(30))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

[htop_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aRqi.png)

For this code, the dependency is n_jobs + 4, but for more complex code with additional queues I did not find the dependency. In the process of execution the number of processes in htop does not change. All processes are terminated at completion, but it slows down my calculations.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I get a parent worker and `n` workers in the pool for `mp.Pool(n)`.
(Tried both, python 2.7 and 3)

Comment: David, what is your os version? My version is Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: I'm on 18.04.4 LTS.